# How is $x!$ continuous for all values greater than $2$?

Tags: continuity

Our (high-school) workbook had a statement that confuses me, since I always viewed the expression $x!$ to be defined for integers only. How is the factorial function defined for decimal numbers ?

Comment: The extension to the real and complex number is the Gamma function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Who says it's continuous for all values greater than $2$? I agree with your assessment: at least from a high school perspective, it cannot be considered continuous, as it is defined only on non-negative integer points.

Comment: The textbook says it's continuous for x>2.

Comment: Well then the textbook is wrong, or at least misleading.

Comment: @cpiegore  To be fair, one has to see the workbook. Perhaps there is a scan available?

Comment: Nope, it's a school-issued textbook, so I'm pretty sure you won't find a scan of it